# Elimination in a tournament

Tags: probability

In a single-elimination tournament, teams are paired up and play head-to-head matches in rounds. After each round, all losers are eliminated, and the winners move on to the next round. The tournament ends when there is only one team left.
Two tournaments are the same if the same matches are played and won by the same teams, and are different otherwise. How many different single-elimination tournaments amongst n teams are possible, where n is a power of two?

How do I begin this question?

Comment: Have you tried by hand for two and four teams?

Comment: Start by picking $n/2$ teams for winning side and then shuffling the losing side to get all permutations. This gives you the possibilities for the first round.

Answer (score 0):

Start by picking any $n/2$ teams for winning side (the rest become losing side) and then shuffling the losing side to get all permutations. This gives you the number of possibilities for the first round.

$$N_1 = {n\choose n/2}\cdot (n/2)!$$

Now using the same rationale, you get the possibilities for the second round by choosing $n/4$ teams for winning side and shuffling to get

$$N_2 = {n/2\choose n/4}\cdot (n/4)!$$

Similarly,

$$N_i ={n/2^{i-1}\choose n/2^i}\cdot (n/2^i)!$$

Since $N_1$, $N_2$ ... $N_i$ are independent events, we multiply them together to get total possibilities

$$N=N_1N_2N_3...$$

$$N=\frac{n!}{(n/2)!(n/4)!(n/8)!...1!}$$